# Yoast: do I still need to manually insert meta tags in my theme or will Yoast do this for me?

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I am using the Yoast Wordpress SEO plugin and would like to know if I need to insert meta tags into the head of my document or will Yoast do this for me assuming I've filled out the required fields in the back-end? Do I still need default meta tags or will Yoast be injecting its own?

Answer (score 1):

It will use what's in your theme to write the meta tags.

Just enable meta tags in the yoast options as by default this is OFF and then go view your site.

[image]

However you'll also need to set something for the Meta field from the Post tab

[image]

You can also choose the option to force titles if your concerned

Comment: It doesn't appear that Yoast is injecting meta tags into my theme when I select this option: "Force rewrite titles" or unselect it. Even when I put in meta tags it's not overwriting them..?

Comment: @Brian ive added some screenshots so you can check your settings